# Trying to connect to SQL server using Tedious Connection and Windows Authentication?

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, tedious

I'm trying to connect to SQL server using tedious connection pool and windows authentication. But I get an error:

> message: 'Login failed for user \'\'.', code: 'ELOGIN'

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the latest version of tedious.

**.env file**

```
SQL_SERVER=localhost
SQL_UNAME=Username
SQL_PSWD=Password
SQL_DB=DatabaseName
SQL_DOMAIN=US
```

**dbController.js**

```
const {Request} = require('tedious');
const TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
const ConnectionPool = require('tedious-connection-pool');
const dbConfig = require('./dbconfig');

const poolConfig = {
    min: 1,
    max: 1,
    log: true
};

let _rows = [];
const pool = new ConnectionPool(poolConfig, dbConfig);

pool.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**dbConfig.js**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
    server: process.env.SQL_SERVER,
    options: {
    instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS',
    encrypt: false,
    database: process.env.SQL_DB,
    rowCollectionOnDone: true,
    useColumnNames: true
    },
    authentication: {
        type: 'ntlm',
        options: {
            userName: process.env.SQL_UNAME,
            password: process.env.SQL_PSWD,
            domain: process.env.SQL_DOMAIN
        }
   }
};
```

Comment: when I enter the names manually without the .env file it still won't work

Comment: https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/311

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `tedious-connection-pool` is using `tedious` version 1 instead of `tedious` version 9.

I'm hoping to solve that with `tedious-connection-pool2` based on a PR I found that never got merged upstream.

So, wait a day, and find my `tedious-connection-pool2` and use the `overrideTedious` option that should work.